# Route Client App To Different Port Backend IIS 10

Tags: azure, routes, listener, iis-10

I have a HTTP Listener that listens for incoming traffic on port 11000 in my Azure VM. I want a client app sending data to that port but without having to type the port in the client app and also using https instead of http.

For instance, when typing the URL in the client app, it would be: https://myurl/data. But in the back end, IIS would re-route to http://myurl:11000/data.

I also have an app that is on 443, so I would want it to route from 443 to 11000.

I followed [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/86bd8375-ac40-4a3e-a9c6-ad98d7756687/how-to-redirect-in-https-from-one-port-to-another?forum=iisurlrewritemodule) article's example but still doesn't route the data stream to my HTTP listener to the port provide in the config file. Would I use redirect or rewrite for the web.config file?

Comment: Learn how to debug rules via FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and then you can help yourself out.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want is that

> `https://myurl/data re-route` to `http://myurl:11000/data`

HTTPS requests can be redirected to HTTP via rewrite rules. But redirecting HTTPS to HTTP is not recommended for many factors.

If you want to send data to port 11000 in the client application, but don't have to type the port in the client application, you need to create the URL rewrite rule on port 80, not on port 11000.

Refer to the following rules and modify it according to your actual requirements:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^data(.*)" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="http://myurl:11000/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Also, you need to double-click `Application Request Routing Cache` at the server level and select `Server Proxy Settings` on the right, then `enable proxy` and apply.

If you haven't installed the ARR module on IIS, you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/installing-application-request-routing-arr/install-application-request-routing-version-2).

Comment: Thank you. I installed the ARR module. Question though, why port 80 and not 11000 where my listener is listening for incoming data? Also you've added 11000 in the example, should it be 80? Do you go by the "Default Website" HTTP port that IIS creates (8080 in my instance)? Is the routing to port 80 because I'm telling the client app to go to a URL that uses HTTP? Furthermore, would I use {C:0} for appended URL from the client app (http://myurl:1100/{R:0}{C:0})?

Comment: You didn't mention port 8080 in your question, your instance used port 80. I didn't understand what you mean clearly, What I want to know is what port is your website deployed on and what URL do you actually want to access the website through?